# onclick not triggering all observers' next()

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I am learning RxJs and trying to simulate the `fromEvent` by creating an observable using `Rx.Observable.create` method. I have two observers for this  and everything works fine. But when I use `onclick` instead of `addEventListener` only the second observer's next method is triggered.

Is this the expected behavior? If so why?

here is what I did -  https://jsfiddle.net/54fwwwwj/

```
let observable = Rx.Observable.create(function(obs){
    btnAction.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{obs.next('A value');});
  //btnAction.onclick = (event)=>{obs.next('A value');};
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're overriding `btnAction.onclick` property multiple times in the `Observable.create` method.

So you see only the second observer because it overrode the `onclick` property after the first observer set its own handler.

Comment: Does that mean each `subscribe` will trigger the creation of observable again and again. That was not my understanding.  :O

Comment: Yes, the callback is called for every new observer.